# What is the difference between passing in argument as object vs string into a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, object, parameters

I have below is a method that signs a user up with their email and password and create a document in Firebase when the user enters their info into a form and clicks submit:

```
const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const { user } = await createAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            console.log(user, 'user')

            await createUserDocumentFromAuth(user, { displayName })
        }catch(err) {
            if(err === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                alert('Account with this email already exists');
                return;
            }else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

For this function call:

```
await createUserDocumentFromAuth(user, { displayName })
```

where `displayName` can be a string, such as `ElonMusk`.
In the actual `createUserDocumentFromAuth`, I am calling the setDoc method, which is one from Firebase to set a user document:

```
export const createUserDocumentFromAuth = async ( userAuth, additionalInfo = {} ) => {
  if(!userAuth) return;
  console.log(additionalInfo, 'additionalInfo')
  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid);
  const userSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);

  if(!userSnapshot.exists()) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();
    try {
      // set the doc here
      await setDoc(userDocRef, {
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalInfo
      });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('err creating the user', err)
    }
  };

  return userDocRef;
}
```

The reason I passed `{ displayName }` in manually is because there is a case where the server's response to `createAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` has `displayName` to be `null`, but we want the user to have a displayName registered in the database.

My question is:

1. Why does `displayName` only work when it is passed in as an object and not just in its normal form? For example:

```
await createUserDocumentFromAuth(user, { displayName })
```

will replace the `displayName: null`
But not when I pass in:

```
await createUserDocumentFromAuth(user, displayName)
```

2. What is this technique called in JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you, so what I was getting at is: How does { displayName: "blah" }  replace displayName: null, since { displayName: "blah" }  is in the object form, but `displayName: null` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into `createUserDocumentFromAuth`, you'll see that it's expects two arguments `userAuth` and `additionalInfo`, both arguments are expected to be objects.

It later uses data from `additionalInfo` to add/overwrite anything in `userAuth` when calling `setDoc()` method.

So, I'd recommend add

```
console.log(userDocRef, {
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalInfo
      });
```

to see what what data is being sent to `setDoc()`

Comment: Thank you, so if Javascript sees: `{displayName: null}` and `{displayName: 'blah'}`, does it actually compare the key and see that they're the same, then gets the latter value?

Comment: See that `...` in front of `additinalInfo` this called [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) what it does it take everything inside the object and merges it into parent object. So basically it ends up as `{displayName: null, displayName: 'blah'}` and since object can only contain unique keys, the value from last key will overwrite first value.